# How can I find the position of another sprite in Snap?

Tags: snap-lang

Using the Snap! programming language, scripts run in the context of their own sprite. I need to know where the sprite is positioned relative to another sprite. How do I find the position of the other sprite?

Answer (score 5):

There's a sensing block called "[costume #] or []", which allows you to get properties on another sprite. The [costume #} can be changed to [x position] or [y position].

Note that you'll have to choose the target sprite in the right dropdown before it lets you change the property in the left dropdown.

[image: [x position] of [Other Sprite] block]

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

If you're only concerned with the relative distance between Sprites, you may try [the distance to other sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27pwc.png). This will give you the distance between the sprite you are editing and the sprite for which you're searching.